# If $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is Riemann integrable then $F(x)=\int_{a}^{x}f(t)dt$ is continuous (verification)

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, solution-verification

Let $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ then $F:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$
with  $F(x)=\int_{a}^{x}f(t)dt$ is continuous.

(with the definition $\delta - \epsilon$)

let $|x-x_0|<\delta$ and let $\epsilon>0$ , consider $\delta= \frac{\epsilon}{M} $ where M is defined as the supremum (later)

now $|F(x)-F(x_0)|=|\int_{a}^{x}f(t)dt - \int_{a}^{x_0}f(t)dt |=|\int_{x_0}^{x}f(t)dt|  \leq \int_{x_0}^{x}|f(t)|dt $ now because $|f(t)|$ is defined in a closed set $[a,b]$ it exists a supremum $M$ for that function so,  $|\int_{x_0}^{x}f(t)dt|  \leq M\int_{x_0}^{x}dt=M(x-x_0)<M \delta=\epsilon$

Is this proof correct? also, when we write the $|x-x_0|$ and $|\int_{x_0}^{x}f(t)dt|$ what we mean is the norm not the absolute value right ?

Comment: Looks ok to me. Norm and absolute value are the exact same thing in this case.

Comment: One small comment. Does your definition of a Riemann integrable function mention that it has to be bounded? Because it not, your argument doesn't work (that argument requires continuity of the function $f$ and boundedness of the interval aswell).